# Raising 10 to the power with e notation for a non-integer power

Tags: python

I am trying to use e notation to raise 10 to the 9.5 power (10^9.5). However, the input 1e9.5 throws an error in Python. But, when I use the same notation for an integer power: 1e9 (i.e 10^9), I get no problems. Is there a way around this? Can e notation not be used with non-integer powers?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just explicitly use ``10**9.5``? The exponential notation is defined only for integer powers as far as I know.

Comment: The `e` notation is only meant for scientific notation, i.e. `3e16` is `3*(10**16)`.  It does not make sense to use scientific notation with any numbers that are not integers since it does not give a sense of magnitude (scientific notation is used to give a sense of magnitude of a number).  For normal exponentiation you shall use `**` (`10**9.5`) as MSeifet points